# Macbook Pro starts with gray screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, startup

When I'm closing the screen on my macbook and tries to start it up a few hours later it always starts with a gray screen. It take about 30 to 60 seconds until I can start using the computer. 
The macbook is brand new. It doesn't matter if the charger is connected or not.

Anyone knows what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an SMC issue to me. SMC is the System Management Controller chip that controls power-centric pieces of the Mac's hardware, such as power, sleep functions, fans, etc. The exact process varies by model of Intel Mac, so I've included the link below.

[Resetting the System Management Controller](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: I tried to reset the SMC. Did not work :/